# Cant seem to access object property in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Console output:

```js
{
  295798: {
    box_type: "QB",
    color: "Assorted",
    floor_allowed: 2100,
    grade: false,
    head_size: null,
    is_special: "0",
    length: false,
    live_inventry: "1",
  }
}
```

I have an array that is shown in the screenshot above in chrome console. when I print out the array it comes up.

```js
console.log(props.thisData);
console.log(props.thisData[0].color);
```

`props.thisData` shows the whole array. However when I try to access the color I get the following error:

`Product.jsx:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure in your console output is not an `Array`. Its an `Object` with numbers as keys. It seems that there is no element with key `0` (no property `0` in the object). Hence, you get undefined.

To access your color property you would have to access it through the key on your object:

```
props.thisData['295798'].color
```

**UPDATE**

I suggest you to convert your object into an array and add the key as an id to each element if you want to work with the Array.

```
const dataArray = Object
  .keys(props.thisData)
  .map(key => ({ id: key, ...props.thisData[key] }))
```

Comment: any idea on how I can get the info then?

Comment: that number is different for each product, so how can I a variable instead of the number itself? props.thisData[ID_HERE].color /

Comment: @mcjanty32 just convert it to an array as in the update